# I am trying to display a toast when this button is pressed. But the code is not working

Tags: android, toast

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String userid = text.getText().toString();
            String pass = text1.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entered"+userid+"and password entered is"+pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

}
```

The code executes successfully, but nothing happens when the button is pressed. 
When I focus on the line in eclipse it says the following

```
"The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new 
 View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)"
```

Please tell me what do i require to do to make it work

Comment: try MainActivity.this in place of geBaseContext()

Comment: You weren't using `getBaseContext()` when you saw that error you were using `this`... You should have tried saving or cleaning your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to pass the current **Context** as first parameter (instead of `getBaseContext()`). This, in your case, is `MainActivity.this`.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Entered"+userid+"and password entered is"+pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!Thanks!
Could you please direct me towards what "context" actually means? I am very new to android app development. And am sure If i know what it is I wont make such mistakes more.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the getBaseContext() at that point in the code is referencing the click listener.  What you want to reference is your activity.  You should change the reference of your Context in the Toast message to be ***View.getContext()***(if working on the context from within a subview) or ***this***.

Comment: `getBaseContext()` cannot reference an OnClickListener, this was a red herring.

Comment: The reason that he was getting the printout of "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new 
 View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)" should be because the argument from getBaseContext passed in was as the error states the View.OnClickListener.

Comment: If you can recreate that error I will be _very_ impressed. The error is most likely left over from `Toast.makeText(this, ...` and the compiler hadn't refreshed / removed that error. Also I've never heard of `Activity.getContext()` is that a typo? If not would you link to its documentation?

Comment: Ah, yes it is.  That would be for a View if he was working through a View within his Activity.  But since poitroae has resolved the question which acceptance, not need for continuation on my part here within this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Entered"+userid+"and password entered is"+pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OR

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Entered"+userid+"and password entered is"+pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Method Syntax

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration);
```

The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.